# Error:(18) error: resource style/Widget.Design.Snackbar (aka com.jlcsoftware.callrecorder:style/Widget.Design.Snackbar) not found

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzxHF.png)I am facing this problem when I create a new project this error show in message view please help me or suggestion.

````
C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.0.2.aar\25b2c273a4f27c6741aa60f11c3823f0\res\layout\design_layout_snackbar.xml

Error:(18) error: resource style/Widget.Design.Snackbar (aka com.jlcsoftware.callrecorder:style/Widget.Design.Snackbar) not found.

C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.0.2.aar\25b2c273a4f27c6741aa60f11c3823f0\res\layout-sw600dp-v13\design_layout_snackbar.xml```
````